# SQL: Where to find raw data of tables used in docs.oracle.com sample SQL queries?

Tags: oracle

I am a beginner to learn SQL and I use docs.oracle.com for my learning. Sample SQL queries provided in this website use some tables and I would like to see the contents from these tables for better understanding but I am unable to find where is it available in that website.

Sample link - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm

In the section named 'Example 21-1 Ranking Order', the below tables are used:
sales, products, customers, times, channels, countries

Comment: Installing the sample schemas is documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC001  (why are you learning Oracle with an outdated and unsupported version?)

Comment: Thanks for the manual! Also, i didn't know this is outdated..